# Retrieving multiple summaries

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

In this scenario there are four tables: TableA, TableB and TableC, TableD and TableE

```
TableA -> TableB = 1-to-many
TableB -> TableC = 1-to-many
TableB -> TableD = 1-to-1
TableC -> TableE = 1-to-1

TableA { Id (PK), Field1 (float), DateField (DateTime) }
TableB { Id (PK), TableAId (FK), TableDId (FK), Field2 (float) }
TableC { Id (PK), TableBId (FK), TableEId (FK), Field3 (float) }
TableD { Id (PK), Type (tinyint) }
TableE { Id (PK), Type (tinyint) }
```

Some, but not all records from TableB contain children records in TableC. Based on some DateRange (from-to), I need to take all records from TableA, and its related records, and Calculate:

- summary of TableA.Field1,
- summary of TableB.Field2, grouped by the TableD.Type (there are 5 different types).
- summary of TableC.Field3, gruped by the TableE.Type (there are 4 different types).

So, the result should contain 10 calculated summaries. What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

**Edit**: here are pseudo queries as example for each summary:

```
SELECT SUM(a.Field1) FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.Id = b.TableAId WHERE a.DateField BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo

SELECT SUM(b.Field2) FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.Id = TableD d ON b.TableDId=d.Id WHERE a.DateField BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo AND d.Type = 1

SELECT SUM(b.Field2) FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.Id = TableD d ON b.TableDId=d.Id WHERE a.DateField BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo AND d.Type = 2 // etc to 5

SELECT SUM(c.Field3) FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.Id = b.TableAId INNER JOIN TableC c ON b.Id=c.TableBId INNER JOIN TableE ON c.TableEId=e.Id WHERE a.DateField BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo AND e.Type = 1 // 3x this query, only type is different
```

Comment: SUM aggregate or some other "summary"? And any grouping?

Comment: SUM aggregate, grouping is required on Field2 and Field3, as mentioned, both groupings are per each Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way here is to write the whole thing in one query with CTE's, and let SQL Server's optimizer figure out the best way to execute this thing. This way we are not:

1. repeating work with multiple queries
2. creating table variables that are not indexed
3. creating temp tables that need to be written to disk

Here's the query:

```
with a as (select * from tableA where datefield between datefrom and dateto),
b as ( select * from tableB where tableB.tableAid = a.id)
    select null, sum(a.field1) from a
union 
    select d.type, sum(b.field2) 
    from b
    join tableD d on d.id = b.tableDid
    group by d.type
union 
    select e.type, sum(c.field3)
    from tableC c
    join b on b.id = c.tableBid
    join tableE e on e.id = c.tableEid
```